# Executes same code more than once. How to use Goto statement inside for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have code which is used more than two times in different condition in same function. So I decided to use Goto statement. But that code will be executed inside for loop. So I don't understand how to call same code in same function. I don't want to create one more function. My code is...

```
- (void)setSelectedSearchCriteria:(NSString *)storedValue storedTag:(NSString *)storedTag D_Key:(NSString *)D_Key D_Tag_Value:(NSString *)D_Tag_Value arrayMain:(NSMutableArray *)arrayMain bgView:(UIView *)bgView
{
    //Add data
    NSMutableArray *sArray = [[storedValue componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *sTagArray = [[storedTag componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];

    [sArray removeObject:@""];
    [sTagArray removeObject:@""];

    int maxTag = 0;
    if (sTagArray.count != 0)
    {
        maxTag = [[sTagArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];
        for (int i = maxTag + 1; i <= [D_Tag_Value intValue]; i++)
            goto add_value;
    }
    else
        goto add_value;

    add_value:
    {
        NSString *D_Value = [[arrayMain objectAtIndex:[D_Tag_Value intValue]] valueForKey:PARAMETER_KEY];
        if (![sArray containsObject:D_Value])
        {
            [sArray addObject:D_Value];
            [sTagArray addObject:D_Tag_Value];
        }

        //Add data
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[bgView viewWithTag:[D_Tag_Value intValue]];
        [self setSelectedButtonStyle:btn];
    }

    storedValue = [[[sArray valueForKey:KEY_DESCRIPTION] componentsJoinedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
    storedTag = [[[sTagArray valueForKey:KEY_DESCRIPTION] componentsJoinedByString:@","] mutableCopy];

    [SEARCH_CRITERIAS setValue:storedValue forKey:D_Key];
    [SEARCH_CRITERIAS_TAG setValue:storedTag forKey:D_Key];
}
```

Code inside add_value executed in for loop and also in else part. So I don't know how to manage this.

Comment: Please no.  Create another method with the common code.

Comment: I want to do so. Because I am adding value in sArray and sTagArray and If I create extra method then I have to returns two array and thats not possible. And aslo I don't want to create two global array for this.

Comment: You can create an object that encapsulates the two arrays and return that, but if you insist on doing it all in one function, simply calculate the number of times you need to iterate the loop (1 in the case that count==0; you can use the ternary operator for that) and then use the code in the loop

Comment: No, you pass the arrays as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a block inside your function

```
void(^theBlock)(void) = ^(){
        NSString *D_Value = [[arrayMain objectAtIndex:[D_Tag_Value intValue]] valueForKey:PARAMETER_KEY];
        if (![sArray containsObject:D_Value])
        {
            [sArray addObject:D_Value];
            [sTagArray addObject:D_Tag_Value];
        }

        //Add data
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[bgView viewWithTag:[D_Tag_Value intValue]];
        [self setSelectedButtonStyle:btn];
};
```

I don't fully understand what do you do in your add_value. If it can change to a block receive some parameters and return some value that would be better

after that you simply call the block

```
theBlock();
```

Comment: I want to know about, If I use block then it will be executed in background or not? And can I pass parameters to block?

Comment: Block won't be executed in background if you didn't dispatch it to background queue.  Block is something that you create like a variable use like a function so of course you can pass parameters to it

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. But I never work on block based coding... If you have any better link than provide me... So I can better understand... I don't know how to pass parameters in block. Can you please help me?

Comment: Thanks, I completed this by using block.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't actually depend on the loop counter, so it isn't too hard to refactor the code so that you can simply execute the loop the appropriate number of times.

```
- (void)setSelectedSearchCriteria:(NSString *)storedValue storedTag:(NSString *)storedTag D_Key:(NSString *)D_Key D_Tag_Value:(NSString *)D_Tag_Value arrayMain:(NSMutableArray *)arrayMain bgView:(UIView *)bgView
{
    //Add data
    NSMutableArray *sArray = [[storedValue componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *sTagArray = [[storedTag componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];

    [sArray removeObject:@""];
    [sTagArray removeObject:@""];

    int loopCount = 1;
    if (sTagArray.count != 0) {
         int maxTag = [[sTagArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];
         loopCount = [D_Tag_Value intValue] - maxTag;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount ; i++) {
        NSString *D_Value = [[arrayMain objectAtIndex:[D_Tag_Value intValue]] valueForKey:PARAMETER_KEY];
        if (![sArray containsObject:D_Value])
        {
            [sArray addObject:D_Value];
            [sTagArray addObject:D_Tag_Value];
        }

        //Add data
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[bgView viewWithTag:[D_Tag_Value intValue]];
        [self setSelectedButtonStyle:btn];
    }

    storedValue = [[[sArray valueForKey:KEY_DESCRIPTION] componentsJoinedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
    storedTag = [[[sTagArray valueForKey:KEY_DESCRIPTION] componentsJoinedByString:@","] mutableCopy];

    [SEARCH_CRITERIAS setValue:storedValue forKey:D_Key];
    [SEARCH_CRITERIAS_TAG setValue:storedTag forKey:D_Key];
}
```